# Initializer list with more than initialization value

Tags: c++, testing, googlemock

I have code like this:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Example {

    Example(): d_variable1(somefunction1), d_variable2(d_variable1, "someString"), d_variable3(somefunction2) {

    }
   

    type1 d_variable1;
    type2 d_variable2;
    type3 d_variable3;

};
```

The part I don't get is:  `d_variable2(d_variable1, "someString")`,

- what is the purpose of `someString` as a 2nd "*argument*"?
- is it even an "*argument*" or does it have a different name?

There's no compilation error so it is valid C++. All this code is in a test/mock file so I don't have actual values to test on. I have to correct/extend this test. I am learning to test but from what I understand, I have to determine what the behavior should be for a mock. I am also trying to understand the source code from the tests. They say that tests are good documentation but reading them now isn't clarifying things so I am starting to ask questions about the small bits of the code.

Comment: What is `type1`, `type2`, `type3`?

Comment: Do you know "constructor"?

Comment: Yes, I know that this is a constructor but I have only used it with one variable/value in the parentheses.

Comment: _The part I don't get is:  d_variable2(d_variable1, "someString")_ I do not understand what you mean by you don't get this. Depending on `type2`, if it had a constructor that allows two arguments, then that should work. This is not possible with something like `int`, as it accepts only one value.

Comment: @Jarod42 Those types are all class types that I don't own.

Comment: Do you understand that [code](https://godbolt.org/z/Yqj9h7cns)?

Comment: _what is the purpose of someString as a 2nd "argument"?_ A constructor can accept more than one argument. And it is still referred to as an argument.

Comment: So, is your question why you are allowed to do this: `d_variable2(d_variable1, "someString")`?

Comment: @Amolgorithm, yes it is.

Comment: @Jarod42, yes. 

I was thinking that if there is a constructor in there, it would be `d_variable2(Constructor(ConstructorArg1, ...))` but not use `d_variable1` as well as `someString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there is a class `Foo` which need not be defined by you:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a, const char* b)
    {
        //...code
    }
};
```

`Foo's` constructor accepts 2 arguments. So, when constructing an object of `Foo`, you need to pass two arguments like this: `Foo(5, "something")`.

Now, let's say that your `type2` is `Foo` (and `type1` & `type3` are `int`).

Then your class `Example` could look like this:

```
class Example {
    Example(): d_variable1(5), d_variable2(d_variable1, "someString"), d_variable3(46) {

    }

    int d_variable1;
    Foo d_variable2;
    int d_variable3;

};
```

`d_variable2` is an object of `Foo`, so when you construct it, it can accept two arguments, which are `d_variable1` and `"someString"`. That is because the sole constructor of `Foo` accepts two arguments. And when you have more than one argument, it is still referred to as arguments.

And my example of `Foo` does not even need to be a class you define. It could be any class; one that could even be part of STL.

Comment: Ok so it syntactic sugar for  `... d_variable2(Foo(d_variable1, "someString"))`?

Comment: I didn't get the part about multiple constructors. The compiler will pick the constructor that accepts the same number and type of arguments?

Comment: @heretoinfinity Which part are you referring to specifically? But anyways, you are right about the: _The compiler will pick the constructor that accepts the same number and type of arguments_.

Comment: @heretoinfinity Yes, you could think of it as syntactic sugar for that statement.